# Default value for an input field on EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm trying my hand at an EF Core MVC app and I've hit a snag:

I've a model that has a RenewDate as follows (excerpt):

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Status")]
public char STATUS { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Licence Renew Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime RENEWDATE { get; set; }
```

I also have a LicenceViewModel exclusively to convert STATUS (char(1)) to a string as follows:

```
public class LicencaViewModel
{
    public Licence Licence { get; set; }
    public string Status 
    {
        get 
        {
            return Licence.STATUS switch
            {
                'P' => "Pending",
                'I' => "Inactive",
                'B' => "Blocked",
                'A' => "Active",
                _ => "Error"
            }; 
        }
        set 
        {
            Licence.STATUS = value switch
            {
                "Pending" => 'P',
                "Inactive" => 'I',
                "Blocked" => 'B',
                "Active" => 'A',
                _ => 'P'
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the relevant lines of Create.cshtml:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Licence.RENEWDATE" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@DateTime.Now" readonly type="date" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Licence.RENEWDATE" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

So, basically what I'm trying to achieve here is a readonly field that simply shows the automatically set renew date for the customer's licence. The way it is now simply shows current date, but I cannot use `@DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)` for I get `Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions`.

I've tried using ViewBag with `ViewBag.AutoRenewDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)` on the controller, as well as ViewData["AutoRenewDate"] on the view itself. I've also tried adding `public DateTime RENEWDATE{ get { return DateTime.Now.AddYears(1); } }` directly to the viewModel, also to no avail.

I've seen lots of answers using pure Html to get dates from ViewBags and ViewModels, but I'd like to know if there's a way to use the razor pages templates to do it...

EDIT: I forgot to explicit that this is the "Create" form page, so I don't have a filled model to set RENEWDATE to. I needed a readonly form field that automatically showed today plus a year.

Comment: If you want just display the value date, you can write `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Licence.RENEWDATE)` and  in conroller set date that you want`RENEWDATE = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)`

Comment: My bad, I forgot to explicit that this is the "Create" page, so I don't have a filled model to set RENEWDATE to.

Comment: Your conversion in your view model from status char to string should probably be done in an automapper mapping from the object to a ViewModel. The ViewModels, themselves, should not contain any logic.

Comment: @TeaBaerd I will keep that in mind! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by simply ignoring whatever the POST method call viewmodel has in the controller script and overwriting the property I needed to set as default on the POST method, as follows:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, manager")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(LicencaViewModel licencaViewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(licencaViewModel);
            licencaViewModel.Licence.STATUS = 'P'; //This overrides whatever licencaViewModel currently has and sets it to the expected value.
            string serial = await _licencaViewModelService.InsertAsync(licencaViewModel.Licenca);
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = serial });
        }
```